# R: missForest Missing Value Imputation Strange Error

Tags: r, dataframe, random-forest, missing-data

I am testing several `time series data-sets with significant holes (missing values)` with various types of Multiple Imputation packages in R. I was able to successfully test with `Hmisc` and `MICE`. However, I am not able to run the `missForest` method although this seems to be the simplest of the three.

Example:
I have a data.frame   `df_final`
There are 2 columns:

```
day_of_year (1,2,3,....365 -> 365 integer values, no NA)
bookings  (279 integer values, 86 NA values)
```

My goal is to fill the 86 NA values with missForest.

Here's my code

```
final.imp <- missForest(df_final, verbose = TRUE)
final.imp$OOBerror
final.imp$error

imputed_df <- final.imp$ximp
```

Here's the error
[image]

How is this possible? Both my columns have the same length = 365.
If the error is due to NA values, then the algorithm defeats it's purpose.
I must be doing something wrong.

The code works perfectly with the iris data-set.

EDIT: Adding the result of dput()

```
> dput(df_final)
structure(list(day_of_year = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 
59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 
75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 
91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 
105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 
118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 
131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 
144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 
157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 
170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 
183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 
196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 
209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 
222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 
235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 
248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 
261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 
274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 
287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 
300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 
313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 
326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 
339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 
352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 
365), bookings = c(6L, 12L, 17L, 0L, 2L, NA, 19L, 25L, 28L, 47L, 
43L, 31L, NA, 10L, 32L, 23L, 55L, 39L, 21L, NA, 10L, 23L, 23L, 
56L, 52L, 33L, NA, 19L, 29L, 39L, 69L, 48L, 32L, NA, 21L, 28L, 
49L, 63L, 51L, 27L, NA, 18L, 25L, 54L, 64L, 61L, 22L, NA, 11L, 
18L, 25L, 13L, 20L, 14L, NA, 31L, 34L, 28L, 47L, 32L, 14L, NA, 
16L, 26L, 49L, 46L, 54L, 22L, NA, 26L, 32L, 44L, 64L, 55L, 34L, 
NA, 18L, 60L, 52L, 55L, 50L, 20L, NA, 7L, 11L, 23L, 13L, 7L, 
NA, NA, 1L, 5L, 16L, 36L, 55L, 19L, NA, 17L, 32L, 52L, 50L, 69L, 
21L, NA, 28L, 37L, 57L, 73L, 65L, 36L, NA, 26L, 16L, 41L, 60L, 
58L, 63L, NA, 7L, NA, 17L, 36L, 67L, 31L, NA, 20L, 32L, 54L, 
60L, 8L, NA, NA, 26L, 31L, 70L, 34L, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 18L, 17L, 
41L, 73L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 31L, 11L, 17L, 26L, 14L, 
2L, 14L, 16L, 10L, 15L, 17L, 6L, 7L, 17L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 46L, 11L, 
8L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 19L, 8L, 3L, 10L, 19L, 6L, 9L, 35L, 17L, 
9L, 27L, 36L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 10L, 12L, 11L, 18L, 22L, 26L, 14L, 
NA, 12L, 20L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 19L, NA, 29L, 25L, 36L, 46L, 55L, 
27L, NA, 15L, 20L, 39L, 47L, 58L, 35L, NA, 23L, 26L, 30L, 53L, 
78L, 29L, NA, 37L, 28L, 38L, 59L, 73L, 21L, NA, 28L, 23L, 35L, 
66L, 54L, 53L, NA, 40L, 15L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 13L, NA, 12L, 30L, 
27L, 30L, 31L, 23L, NA, 43L, 27L, 29L, 79L, 62L, 30L, NA, 36L, 
25L, 51L, 55L, 55L, 32L, NA, 21L, 20L, 56L, 50L, 60L, 43L, 27L, 
NA, 27L, 22L, 39L, 48L, 67L, 25L, NA, 31L, 23L, 56L, 58L, 56L, 
22L, NA, 22L, 33L, 51L, 30L, 53L, 15L, NA, 9L, 15L, 41L, 36L, 
47L, 14L, NA, 10L, 11L, 38L, 40L, 53L, 12L, NA, 11L, 23L, 26L, 
52L, 39L, 18L, NA, 5L, 19L, 24L, 27L, 13L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 
7L, NA, 3L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -365L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Don't know why the booking values are displayed as double numeric.

But their data-type is integer.

```
> typeof(df_final$bookings)
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: Could you possibly `dput()` your data?

Comment: Added the dput(df_final).

Comment: Your example data frame leads to a different error for me

Comment: I don't know if this is your real dataset - but mice, hmisc, missForest would be a completely wrong choice for a univariate time series (which this would be, because the first column is only a incremental number). These packages employ inter-variable correlations (in the rows) in order to replace the missing data. Here no correlations between variable 1 and 2 can be found by just looking at the rows.

Comment: What would you suggest? The reason for doing the imputation is that I am using FFT on the completed time series to capture dominant frequencies for day of year patterns. Linear interpolation introduces several unnecessary low frequency peaks in the spectral output, whereas replacing NA by zeroes also biases the estimation to a degree. So, I thought I will use imputation to ensure the statistical properties of the signal won't be changed drastically.